# Including custom logic while combining value from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working with SQL Server 2008.

I construct a dynamic sql like this (which is actually a subquery in another select, which I eventually 'execute'; query simplified for brevity):

```
select (select ', ' + value from 
     (select 'Condition1' value, '0' replace, 1 [order] 
      UNION ALL
      select 'State2' value, '0' replace, 2 [order] 
      UNION ALL
      select 'Something3' value, '1' replace, 3 [order]     )   temptbl 
      for xml path('')) as Result
```

... and this correctly returns the **Result** column with values like:
**',Condition1, Something3'**, etc.

However, instead of simply appending ALL the values in my temptbl rows, I want to "replace" instead "append" when I encounter **replace = '1'** (like in the 3rd row above).

So, if you execute the above, you will get:
', Condition1, State2, Something3'

Instead I need 'Something3' because replace = 1 in the 3rd row above.

Is this possible?

Comment: we need sample data an expected output for this

Comment: scsimon, please see update above. The sql is executable. And mentioned the expectation.

Comment: but you are hard coding the `1` so I don't get it... i think you've simplified this too much.

Comment: Edited Description.(The above will be part of another select like: select (above sql) as field1 from mytable.)

Comment: The "easy" answer is to use a cursor and process one row at a time. An alternative is to group rows up to a `Replace = '1'` (or `1`) row and then generate the list or replacement depending on the existence of a suitable `Replace` row. Sounds like a job for a CTE. How complex can things get, e.g. multiple replacements or a replacement that is not at the end on the list?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what would happen if there was a row after a replace row. I have assumed that if there is a another row after the something3 row, you want it added to the string. I've added a "Something4" row to your test data as an example.

You can ignore any data before the last replace, so you need to figure out where the (last) replace is, and only run from there. If there is no replace, then you get everything. The below example would give you ", Something3, Something4"

```
With Testdata as (
select 'Condition1' value, '0' replace, 1 [order] 
      UNION ALL
      select 'State2' value, '0' replace, 2 [order] 
      UNION ALL
      select 'Something3' value, '1' replace, 3 [order]
      UNION ALL
      select 'Something4' value, '0' replace, 4 [order]
)
Select (
    select ', ' + value
    From Testdata
    Where [order] >=  ISNULL((Select MAX([order]) from Testdata where replace = 1) ,0)
    for xml path('')) as result
```

EDITED: A version without the CTE (with) - just replace each TestData call with the entire contents of the CTE (WITH section) like so. I'm sure you could optimise the second subquery a bit, depending on how the it connects to the parent, but this brute force way works.

```
Select (
    select ', ' + value
    From (
        select 'Condition1' value, '0' replace, 1 [order] 
        UNION ALL
        select 'State2' value, '0' replace, 2 [order] 
        UNION ALL
        select 'Something3' value, '1' replace, 3 [order]
        UNION ALL
        select 'Something4' value, '0' replace, 4 [order]
) a
    Where [order] >=  
       ISNULL((Select MAX([order]) from (
          select 'Condition1' value, '0' replace, 1 [order] 
          UNION ALL
          select 'State2' value, '0' replace, 2 [order] 
          UNION ALL
          select 'Something3' value, '1' replace, 3 [order]
          UNION ALL
          select 'Something4' value, '0' replace, 4 [order]
          ) b
       where replace = 1) ,0)
    for xml path('')) as result
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already figured this with, with. However in my scenario, this entire sql is a subquery of another like this: "select (my entire sql above) as MyResult from MyTable". So, can't use with clause.

Comment: I've added another version without the CTE (With).